# Can you call a function of typescript you initialized in the html file

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

I'm trying to call a function when a button is pressed. The problem is I initialized the function in the html file and the button, when i press it does not see the function.

Ive tried using the < script> tags but it still does not see the function

```
<head>

  <script type="text/javascript">

function openEx1(){
    console.log("Hi");
    this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
  }
</script>

</head>

<body>
<ion-content padding no-bounce>


 <img class = "background" src="../../assets/imgs/Backgroundreal.jpg" 
alt="Background">    


  <button ion-button clear class = "menu" (click) ="openEx1()">     
  </button>



</ion-content>
</body>
```

It says the function is undefined. When I write the function the the .ts file it can read it so i want to know if I can initialize the function directly in the html file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define your javascript after the body tag:

```
<body>
...
<body/>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openEx1(){
    ...
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

I haven’t get this syntax 
‘
  ’,
the ‘(click)’ change to ‘onclick’,you can try it.

Another reason,put  tag after the